# ¿Como cambiar masivamente los valores de las propiedades de un objeto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, poo

Imaginemos que tengo un objeto no iterable tal que así:

```
let objeto = {
    color: 'verde',
    fondo: 'verde',
    icono: 'rojo',
    detalles: 'verde',
    borde: 'rojo'
}
```

Imaginemos que objeto tiene como 100 propiedades diferentes, como hago para cambiar, todos los valores de verde a azul, por ejemplo, sin tener que ir de una en una?

Answer (score 6):

Un objeto es iterable, podes usar un for u otras estructuras.
Lo podrias hacer asi:

```js
let objeto = {
    color: 'verde',
    fondo: 'verde',
    icono: 'rojo',
    detalles: 'verde',
    borde: 'rojo'
}

for(let i in objeto){
 if(objeto[i] === "verde"){
  objeto[i] = "azul"
 }
}

console.log(objeto)
```

Podrias hacer un funcion a la que le pases el objeto,
la palabra que queres eliminar y la palabra que queres agregar,
y te queda algo reutilizable para cambiar cualquier palabra

```js
let objeto = {
  color: 'verde',
  fondo: 'verde',
  icono: 'rojo',
  detalles: 'verde',
  borde: 'rojo'
}

const cambiarValor = (obj, oldValue, newValue) => {
  for(let i in obj){
    if(objeto[i] === oldValue){
      objeto[i] = newValue
    }
  }
  return obj
}

console.log(cambiarValor(objeto, "rojo", "violeta"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Recorres el objeto, accedes a sus claves con [**`Object.keys()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) e indicar que si el valor de la clave es `verde`, lo cambias por azul. Ejemplo:

```js
let objeto = {
    color: 'verde',
    fondo: 'verde',
    icono: 'rojo',
    detalles: 'verde',
    borde: 'rojo'
};

Object.keys(objeto).forEach(function(clave) {
    if (objeto[clave] === 'verde') {
        objeto[clave] = 'azul';
    }
});

console.log(objeto);
```